Postgres group rows based on data in one row
I am trying to group rows on a postgres query. I have one row of data that has a field with a line number in it. The next 3 rows are null. I want to set them to the same value as the first row. Then the 5th row repeats the process. There may be 1 or more rows with null as the line number.
Here is a sample of the data with a simple query to pull the rows I want, ordered by line_num:



item_id
ordered_qty
unit
line_num
group_line_num
code




NP4484140T
11
PST^
7
7



COL48LPT
6
PST
8
null
NP4484140T


COL48EPT
4
PST
9
null
NP4484140T


COL48BPT
1
PST
10
null
NP4484140T


VP5578135T
1
PST^
52
52



ONTP48CPT
1
PST
53
null
VP5578135T



I want group_line_num to be 7 where it is null in the first set and 52 on the 4th null. The groups can also be created based on where the unit changes with the PST^ being the defining line of the group. I have tried using lag but since the number of null lines is variable I am not sure how to make it work.

SQL data is unordered by default. The order you present the data above is not guaranteed. Therefore unless you have field that you ORDER BY to get the displayed order I don't see how this can be made to work.

@AdrianKlaver I edited my post. I do have the order by already in. Hope that makes more sense.

The described results can be easily achieved using MAX as a window function.
The following code establishes a table of example values:
CREATE TABLE examples (
  item_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  ordered_qty INTEGER NOT NULL,
  unit TEXT NOT NULL,
  line_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
  group_line_num INTEGER,
  code TEXT
);

INSERT INTO
  examples (
    item_id,
    ordered_qty,
    unit,
    line_num,
    group_line_num,
    code
  )
VALUES
  ('NP4484140T', 11, 'PST^', 7, 7, ''),
  ('COL48LPT', 6, 'PST', 8, NULL, 'NP4484140T'),
  ('COL48EPT', 4, 'PST', 9, NULL, 'NP4484140T'),
  ('COL48BPT', 1, 'PST', 10, NULL, 'NP4484140T'),
  ('VP5578135T', 1, 'PST^', 52, 52, ''),
  ('ONTP48CPT', 1, 'PST', 53, NULL, 'VP5578135T');

To determine the group_line_num using it's most recent non-NULL value, run the following:
SELECT
  item_id,
  ordered_qty,
  unit,
  line_num,
  MAX(group_line_num) OVER (ORDER BY line_num) AS group_line_num,
  code
FROM
  examples
ORDER BY
  line_num;

The following query derives group_line_num from the most recent line_num associated with unit = 'PST^':
SELECT
  item_id,
  ordered_qty,
  unit,
  line_num,
  MAX(line_num) FILTER (WHERE unit = 'PST^') OVER (ORDER BY line_num) AS group_line_num,
  code
FROM
  examples
ORDER BY
  line_num;

The two queries return identical results:



item_id
ordered_qty
unit
line_num
group_line_num
code




NP4484140T
11
PST^
7
7
null


COL48LPT
6
PST
8
7
NP4484140T


COL48EPT
4
PST
9
7
NP4484140T


COL48BPT
1
PST
10
7
NP4484140T


VP5578135T
1
PST^
52
52



ONTP48CPT
1
PST
53
52
VP5578135T




Although it is possible to solve this with window functions it is not entirely straightforward and I think that the simplest solution is to self join the previous rows and identify the row with the highest value of group_line_num which can be used to replace a null value in the current row.
create table example (
    item_id varchar not null,
    ordered_qty integer not null,
    unit varchar not null,
    line_num integer not null,
    group_line_num integer,
    code varchar not null
    );

insert into example (item_id, ordered_qty, unit, line_num, group_line_num, code)
values ('NP4484140T', 11, 'PST^', 7, 7, ''),    
       ('COL48LPT', 6, 'PST', 8, null, 'NP4484140T'),
       ('COL48EPT', 4, 'PST', 9, null, 'NP4484140T'),
       ('COL48BPT', 1, 'PST', 10, null, 'NP4484140T'),
       ('VP5578135T', 1, 'PST^', 52, 52, ''),
       ('ONTP48CPT', 1, 'PST', 53, null, 'VP5578135T');

select item_id,
       ordered_qty,
       unit,
       line_num,
       coalesce(example.group_line_num, previous.group_line_num) as group_line_num,
       code
from example
left join lateral (select previous.group_line_num
                   from example as previous
                   where previous.line_num < example.line_num
                   order by previous.group_line_num desc nulls last
                   limit 1) as previous on true
order by line_num;

